# Need help in resampling the observations in R by sequential elimination of data

Tags: r

The dput of my data is

```
structure(list(x = c(12L, 4L, 7L, 2L), 
               y = c(22L, 18L, 19L, 21L), 
               z = c(22L, 20L, 34L, 21L)), 
          row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

The data frame looks like:

```
   x  y  z
1 12 22 22
2  4 18 20
3  7 19 34
4  2 21 21
```

I need to do the following:

1. Creating a data frame from an existing data frame by eliminating two observations at time.
2. Repeating this step until all the combinations of two observations are being eliminated. To be clear, eliminating the first and second observations to create first new data frame; eliminating first and third observations to make second new data frame, and so on until all the combinations of first observations with other observations are eliminated. Repeating the same process for the combinations second observation with other observations.

*Note: No need to create a new data frame for the combinations which have already been considered previously.*

3. Compiling all these new data frames into a single data frame by rbind

My new data frame would look like this

```
x   y   z
7   19  34
2   21  21
4   18  20
2   21  21
4   18  20
7   19  34
12  22  22
2   21  21
12  22  22
7   19  34
12  22  22
4   18  20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

combn(nrow(df), 2) %>%
  apply(2, function(x) df[-x,]) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

where `df` is your `data.frame`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I just need one more clarification on what if I want to have all the new data frames in a list instead of bind_rows.

Comment: just remove `bind_rows()` (also remove `%>%` from previous row)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have become much dumb these days.